# Generic linked entity in entity framework

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm developing an application where I have the need to store 0, 1 or many comments and 0, 1 or many attachments against each and every entity in my model.

To do so, I'm thinking of developing an entity with columns like:
`id [pk]    tableName    tableId    comment
  1         'Order'          123    'This is some comment'
  2         'Order'          123    'This is antoher comment'
  3         'Order'          124    'This is comment to another order'
  4         'Customer'        56    'This is comment linked to a customer'`

So instead of adding a commentId to each and every entity, I can just link my comments in this generic entity with a tableName and tableId field.

Now... When using entity framework navigation properties, I don't really see a built-in way of navigating to the right records from my Invoice or Customer table. Can this be achieved by making your own navigation properties somehow?

If not..... is there another way how I can achieve a similar result.

Thanks!

Comment: Just for those who are interested: this is exactly what "any-type" mapping in NHibernate is doing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are describing a normal one-to-many relationship.  You should store your main entity in 1 table, and your linked entities in another:

```
id    entityname    entityProperty
1     FirstEntity   Im a property
2     SecondEntity  Me too

id    entityid      comment
1     1             This is a comment
2     1             This is also a comment
3     2             This might be a comment

id    entityid      attachment
1     1             This is an attachment
2     2             This is also an attachment
3     2             This might be an attachment
```

If you are planning to use code first, you might want to have a look at this:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Hello Kevin, thank you for your answer, but it would not work for me. You are indeed describing a normal one-to-many relationship. In my case it can happen that my primary key (id) value for my customer entity might be the same as my primary key (id) value for my order entity for example, so you will retrieve comments and attachments which are not linked to the proper entity.

Comment: If you are storing customers and orders in the same table, you should also consider splitting them up into separate tables, or add a real pk. Your pk should always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue you are going to run into here is that you will need a FK reference back to the table for what record this comment is for.  Thus, you'd need a bunch of nullable properties that point back to the appropriate record for each table that could be stored in here.  That isn't the greatest solution as each new table requires a new column on the Comment table (but this is an option if you want to use navigation properties).  Thus, I don't think EF navigation properties are going to work since you wouldn't be able to use the same 2 FKs to point to multiple tables.

The only other thing I can think of doing isn't as nice.  You'd have to build up the query manually and make a ICollection that is not mapped on each parent.  Then you'd have to build up the comment list yourself.  However, this isn't too difficult, just more annoying.